# How to find the key which has the highest value in a c# dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary and I want to find the key which has the highest value.

For example if I had

```
Key  |  Value
a    |   1
b    |   2
c    |   3
```

I would want c to be returned.

I have this at the moment but it only searches for the highest value, I'm not sure how to return the key.

```
var max = occurrences.Max(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var maxKey = occurrences.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to include **[`MoreLinq`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/wikis/OperatorsOverview.wiki)** and use **`MaxBy`**

```
var result = occurrences.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;
```

Comment: This is great! MoreLinq sound cool! I didn't know about this. Well played!

Comment: Me too didnt know there is a library MoreLinq. Good to know

Answer (score 0):

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        dict.Add("a",1);
        dict.Add("b",2);
        dict.Add("c",3);

        var max= dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Remember to check if max is null.

Answer (score 0):

Also here is a solution that consider if there were more than one key with the max value in the dictionary?

```
Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
dic.Add('a', 1);
dic.Add('b', 2);
dic.Add('c', 3);
dic.Add('d', 3);

var maxValue = (int)dic.Max(i => i.Value);

List<char> maxKeys = dic.Where(i => i.Value == maxValue).Select(i => i.Key).ToList();
```